# How to connect infobright DB through perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, infobright

How to connect infobright DB through perl ?

Answer (score 2):

With [DBD-mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql). Install it with

```
perl Makefile.PL --mysql_config=/usr/local/infobright-3.5.2-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
```

or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to Infobright using any standard database connection that you'd use with MySQL.  Daxim is correct -- DBD is one of the most common ways to connect to the database.  In your DBD config, all you'd need to do is change the port number from 3306 (MysQL) to 5029 (Infobright).  All the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT **

```
if (textBox4.Text == "")
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Please provide Selling1 ", "Item Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            textBox4.Focus();
            return;
        }

        int i = dbcon.writer("insert into Item_Master(Item_Code,Name,Description,Selling1,Selling2,Reorder_level,Reorder_Quantity,Active) Values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "')");

        if (i == 1)
        {


            MessageBox.Show("Record added succesfully", "Item Table");
            Itemview();//disply ll 
           iclear();
        }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("Record unsuccesfully for Item "); }

    }
```

**INSERT **

```
Dbcontrol dbcon = new Dbcontrol();
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

**VIEW/SEARCH**

```
   listView1.Items.Clear();
        dr = dbcon.reader("select cateid,brand,type,deta,date from emcategory where cateid like '%" + txtseacrchid.Text + "%'");

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string sid = dr["cateid"].ToString();
            string id = dr["brand"].ToString();
            string pname = dr["type"].ToString();
            string dis = dr["deta"].ToString();
            string tim = dr["date"].ToString();
            string[] row = { sid, id, pname, dis, tim };
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
            listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);

        }
```

**VIEW/SEARCH***

**UPDATE **

```
     try
        {
            DialogResult x = MessageBox.Show("Do You Really Want To Update This Record", "Cash Book Details", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (x == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                upate.Enabled = true;
                delete.Enabled = false;
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {

                    txtid.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                    txtBrand.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    txttyp.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
                    txtdec.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;


                }


            }


        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

**UPDATE **

**DELETE**

```
DialogResult x = MessageBox.Show("Do You Really Want To Delete This Record", "Item Category", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (x == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            delete.Enabled = true;
            int i = dbcon.writer("delete from Ritemcategory where cateid='" + txtid.Text + "'");

            if (i == 2 || i == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Deleted Succesfully", "Item Category");
                view();

                generatePid();


            }

        }
        else
        {
            delete.Enabled = false;

        }
```

**DELETE**

Answer (score 0):

STOREDPROCEDURE

```
public void generatePid()

        {

            dr = dbcon.reader("Genarate_itemcategory_id");

            while (dr.Read())

            {

                txtid.Text = dr["value"].ToString();

            }

    }

//////////////////KEYDOWN////////////

//////////////////

//////////////////KEYPRESS////////////

//////////////////

//////////////////SELECTEDVALUE////////////

 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            upate.Enabled = false;
            Save.Enabled = false;


                delete.Enabled = true;
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    txtid.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                    txtBrand.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                    txttyp.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
                    txtdec.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;

            }
        }


//////////////////

//////////////////KEYDOWN////////////


 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)

            {



                insert();

            }


//////////////////

 public void log()

      {

          dr = dbcon.reader("select * from Admin where id = ' 1'");
          while (dr.Read())
          {

              string un = dr["fuser"].ToString();
              string ped = dr["fpassword"].ToString();
              if ((textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == null) || (textBox2.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == null))
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Please enter username and password");
              }

              else
              {
                  if (textBox1.Text == un && textBox2.Text == ped)
                  {
                      logdetail();

                  }

                  else
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show("User Name or Password is incorrect");
                  }
              }

          }


      }


//////////////////KEYDOWN////////////




//////////////////
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Dataconnection
{

    public static SqlConnection NewCon;
    //public static string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;      

    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        NewCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Absar;Initial Catalog=star_fancy_stock;Integrated Security=True;");

        return NewCon;
    }

}
```

///////////////////////
2ND
//////////////////

```
namespace star_fancy_stock
{

class Dbcontrol
{

    public static SqlConnection NewCon;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    public int dataread = 0;
    public Dbcontrol()
    { }
    public SqlDataReader reader(String sql)
    {

        try {


        NewCon = Dataconnection.GetConnection();
        NewCon.Open();
        SqlCommand newconn = new  SqlCommand(sql, NewCon);

        dr = newconn.ExecuteReader(); 
        return dr;

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return dr; }

    }


    public int writer(String sql)
    {

        try
        {

            dataread = 0;
            NewCon = Dataconnection.GetConnection();
            NewCon.Open();
            SqlCommand newconn = new SqlCommand(sql, NewCon);

            dataread = newconn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            NewCon.Close();
            return dataread;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return dataread; }

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a really poor question that should have been closed in the first place - but it still asks for a solution in Perl.